# How to use JavaMail to send emails containing UNICODE characters?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm writing codes for a reset-password page (using JSP/Servlet). Here are my codes.

- EmailUtility Class

```
    public class EmailUtility {
    
        public static void sendEmail(String host, String port, String socketFactoryClass, String auth,
                                     final String senderEmail, String senderName, final String password,
                                     String recipientEmail, String subject, String message) throws MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    
            //Get properties object
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", port);
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", socketFactoryClass);
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", auth);
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
            //Get Session
            Authenticator authenticator = new javax.mail.Authenticator()
            {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(senderEmail, password);
                }
            };
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, authenticator);
            //Create a new e-mail message
            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(senderEmail, senderName));
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipientEmail));
            msg.setSubject(subject);
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());
            msg.setText(message);
            //Send the e-mail
            Transport.send(msg);
    
        }
    }
```

- My servlet controlling password reset

```
@WebServlet(name = "ResetPasswordController", urlPatterns = {"/ResetPassword"})
public class ResetPasswordController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String host;
    private String port;
    private String socketFactoryClass;
    private String auth;
    private String email;
    private String name;
    private String pass;

    public void init() {
        // reads SMTP server setting from web.xml file
        ServletContext context = getServletContext();
        host = context.getInitParameter("host");
        port = context.getInitParameter("port");
        socketFactoryClass = context.getInitParameter("socketFactoryClass");
        auth = context.getInitParameter("auth");
        email = context.getInitParameter("email");
        name = context.getInitParameter("name");
        pass = context.getInitParameter("pass");
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String recipient = request.getParameter("reset-email");
        String subject = "Mật khẩu của bạn đã được đặt lại";

        CustomerServices customerServices = new CustomerServices();
        String newPassword = customerServices.resetCustomerPassword(recipient);

        String content = "Xin chào, đây là mật khẩu mới của bạn đã được hệ thống tạo ra ngẫu nhiên: " + newPassword;
        content += "\nChú ý: vì lí do bảo mật, bạn phải đổi mật khẩu ngay sau khi đăng nhập.";
        content += "\nĐội ngũ hỗ trợ UNIFOOD";

        String message = "";

        try
        {
            EmailUtility.sendEmail(host, port, socketFactoryClass, auth, email, name, pass,
                    recipient, subject, content);
            message = "Mật khẩu của bạn đã thay đổi, hãy kiểm tra email của bạn!";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            message = "Có lỗi xảy ra: " + ex.getMessage();
        }
        finally
        {
            request.setAttribute("message", message);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/message.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
    }

        protected void doGet (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws
        ServletException, IOException {
            String url = "/reset-password.jsp";
            request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
        }
}
```

I ran into a problem that all of the emails sent by this way couldn't contain all UNICODE characters. Some characters are replaced by `?`, as you can see in this picture [EmailSent(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fW0v.png)

In the EmailUtility class above, I tried using this command `msg.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");` to fix this error as suggested by one post on this page, but it didn't work. I also tried using the `setText()` with two arguments like `setText(message, "UTF-8")` but there was no `setText()` function that takes 2 arguments.

However, the strange thing is, when I wrote `main()` function in EmailUtility class similar to `sendEmail()` function and ran the code in console,

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        String port = "465";
        String socketFactoryClass = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";
        String auth = "true";
        String senderEmail = "mySenderEmail";
        String password = "myPassword";
        String senderName = "UNIFOOD-SUPPORT";
        String recipientEmail = "myRecipientEmail";
        String subject = "Mật khẩu của bạn đã được đặt lại";
        String message = "Xin chào, đây là mật khẩu mới của bạn đã được hệ thống tạo ra ngẫu nhiên: ";
        message += "\nVì lí do bảo mật, bạn phải đổi mật khẩu ngay sau khi đăng nhập.";
        message += "\nĐội ngũ hỗ trợ UNIFOOD";

        //Get properties object
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", socketFactoryClass);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", auth);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
        //Get Session
        Authenticator authenticator = new javax.mail.Authenticator()
        {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(senderEmail, password);
            }
        };
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, authenticator);
        //Create a new e-mail message
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(senderEmail, senderName));
        msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipientEmail));
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        msg.setText(message);
        //Send the e-mail
        Transport.send(msg);
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
```

the emails I received didn't miss any UNICODE characters, as you can see in this picture [EmailSent(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSbTC.png)

Please help me to fix this error, thank you very much!

Comment: That can happen if the source code file of the Java class is not saved using UTF-8. Check your editor settings etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, BalusC. I have checked my IDE and all files are saved using UTF-8, but this error still exists.

Answer (score 0):

use msg.setContent(message, "text/html; charset=utf-8") instead of  msg.setText(message);